# Unable to read prop in a React functional component passed via Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-functional-component

Here is the sample react functional component

```
const GreetingPage = (props) => {
  console.log("console log", props)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello </h1>;
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStatetoProps = (state) => ({
  user: getUser(state)
});


export default connect(mapStatetoProps)(GreetingsPage)
```

When I do `console.log(props)` it shows me the following

[image]

If you see there is a user object there present.

I retrieve that user from props using following

```
 const { user } = props
  console.log("second log", user)
```

And I am shown the user data

```
    props.user: {
  "uuid": "7dd2sdfs2-c48f-40bb-98d2-251215911d4b",
  "created_at": "2019-11-08T10:03:36.838000Z",
  "username": "joe012",
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "name": "Joe",
  "phone_number": null,
  "do_refresh": false,
  "plan": null,
}
```

Finally, when I want to get the name of the user `console.log(user.name)`

It says

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of null
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Can you include the code for `getUser`?

Comment: Try to log like this: `console.log('props.user:',JSON.stringify(props.user,undefined,2))`

Comment: @HMR updated the output the way you said.

Comment: @whatf Something is missing in your question, you cannot log `props` and have `props.user` be an object but on the next line have `props.user` be null when trying to log `props.user.name` unless you mutate state but then the JSON.stringify would log null. Can you produce a minimal example that demonstrates this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you mentioned you're calling `console.log(user.name)` but it seems you should be calling `console.log(user.username)`. I assume this was just a typing error and is probably not the cause of the problem but please double check that to make sure.

Assuming that's not what's causing the problem, another possibility is the fact that the user object is retrieved asynchronously. If your component renders multiple times and the user object is `null` for the first render(s) and then once the user object is retrieved, the component then rerenders with the user object attached to props, then that is certainly what is happening. When you call

```
const { user } = props
console.log("second log", user)
```

It doesn't throw an error if props.user is null at first. But when you call `user.username`, that does throw an error since you cannot call a property on null or undefined. To fix this, you must make some kind of a check that `user` is not `null` before calling `user.username`. For example:

```
if(user) {
  console.log(user.username)
}
```

Or if you use ES2020 or TS 3.7+, you could use optional chaining:
`user?.username` so that if user is falsy then it will just log `undefined` instead of throwing an error.

A third possibility is the `get` method in lodash in which you would put `_.get(user, 'username')` in order to ensure the user object is not null before calling an attribute on it.

Comment: both user and username are present. calling any user / username throws error.

Comment: Could you post the entire output of the console.log calls when you render the component?

Comment: Also, did you try my suggestion before downvoting it because it might be useful to give it a try just to see if it works...

Answer (score 0):

Can your try this: 1.Destructuring props

```
const GreetingPage = ({user}) => {
console.log(user)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello </h1>;
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStatetoProps = (state) => ({
  user: getUser(state)
});


export default connect(mapStatetoProps)(GreetingsPage)
```

Or 2.Destructuring Child element

```
const GreetingPage = ({user:{username}}) => {
console.log(user)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello </h1>;
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStatetoProps = (state) => ({
  user: getUser(state)
});


export default connect(mapStatetoProps)(GreetingsPage)
```

Or 3.Parsing object before sending it as porps

```
const GreetingPage = ({user}) => {
console.log(user)
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello </h1>;
    </div>
  )
}

const mapStatetoProps = (state) => ({
  user: JSON.parse(getUser(state))
});


export default connect(mapStatetoProps)(GreetingsPage)
```